# Ellipses Operator in C Mingw

Tags: c

I know that the ellipses operator is used to implement variable arguments in function interface. I was wondering however if the 3 ellipses are some sort of macro or a builtin C construct. I was looking through the Mingw headers and can't seem to find any definition for this macro. I don't seem to have stdvar.h and varargs.h is empty. If indeed the ellipses are a macro can someone direct me to their implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a macro. Its a part of the language itself, so a "builtin C construct".

Cant find a good reference, but [google results](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=...+ellipses+c+function&aq=0&oq=ellipses+c+f&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l2j60l3.5698&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) alternate between calling them `operator` and `specifier`